# Update Links Prompt Always Appears After Testing a VBA in my Personal Macro Folder

Tags: vba, excel, command-prompt

I was testing a VBA (found on this site) that opened a specific worksheet from a shared drive location(the doc did not have to be open). I tried putting it in my Personal VBA module so I could load this doc no matter which workbook I am in. After doing so, I get the "Update Links" Prompt every single time I open any new or older excel doc. that I have. I deleted the VBA code but I am still getting this prompt every single time.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Formula Tab and Click on "Names Manager" have a look if there are any named vars using the external link.
Good luck!